# How to open camera app directly on web app using input tag and capture attribute?

Tags: html, input, android-webview, android-camera, ios-camera

I am working on image / pdf upload from a web page on Android phone (in webview) -
1. On button1 click, I want to open camera directly when clicking a button, currently it shows image chooser with files, camera, complete action options. 
2. On button2 click, need to open only Files options(accepting pdf and images) and not camera.

For Q1 - I have tried capture="camera", capture="capture", capture="user", capture="environment" but all of them opens images chooser with all options.

For Q2 - I have tried accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" , accept="application/pdf,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif"

This is my html code:

```
    <input type="file" id="uploadFile" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" style="display:none;"/>
    <input type="file" id="capture" accept="image/*" capture="capture" style="display:none;">
```

note:

```
<input type="file" id="capture" accept="image/*" capture="capture" style="display:none;">
```

**This triggers direct camera app on iOS app. but android shows all file upload options.**

it shows below error when using capture="user"
[image]

Comment: Where is the documentation for this capture attribute? I'm not seeing anything on mdn.

Comment: Hmmm. Looking at this: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/ notice the section on user security and privacy. Being able to open the camera app directly (with no intermediate step from the user) would probably violate that. Plus with it not being documented on Mozilla's dev site, that would suggest it's not well adopted across browsers yet.

Comment: Then again, it seems to work fine on my Android phone with Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/8eLcgo9h/

Comment: @Anthony it's  on MDN too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#capture

Comment: @Anthony we have an android app that runs webview but loading all the web app pages. so this webview may not be not supporting all chrome features

Comment: Hey I missed that you're running a native app with Webview, are you using some framework like phonegap? Do you really need it to be made from this attribute? You probably have access to the same feature browsers do. Or a 100% web workaround would be to make it all yourself, using the [MediaCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) API instead.

Comment: @newdeveloper - ahhhhh. I was looking under the input type image not file.

Comment: @Kaiido we are not using any special framework here. its only mvc code running on hybrid app.

Comment: Sorry I'll move the discussion we had on my now deleted answer back here. So you said that using the [specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/#the-capture-attribute) value `"user"` does trigger something to tell you it's invalid? Can you specify exactly what does expose this error message?

Comment: @Kaiido I added picture in my question. have a look.

Comment: So that's just your IDE that's not compliant with the current HTML specs... Now, maybe webview isn't either, but I really don't know much about webview (I guess there are versioning there too?). At least, my *stock* browser on Android 7.0 does support it.